# Azure functions Core Tools can't install extensions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to install Azure functions Core Tools and extensions by following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local).

```
func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB --version 3.0.0-beta6
```

However it returns this error:

```
No such file or directory
```

I'm using these software versions:

- MacOS v10.13.3
- azure-functions-core-tools@2.0.1-beta.25
- node v9.10.1 (npm v5.8.0)
- also tried with node v8.9.3 (npm v5.8.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for `func extensions` commands you'll need `dotnet` on your path. 
Please install `.NET Core SDK` for mac OS from here https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/macos/build

This [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/367) is tracking removing this requirement. We probably should display a better error message though. I just opened [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/421) to track that. Also added it to the [readme here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#known-issues)